# How To Stop A Internet Explorer PopUp From Occurring?

Tags: internet-explorer, blueprism

I have an automated RPA process running on a JDE system. I have noticed that on some of our machines the attached popup happens causing the job fail.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer steps below to disable this popup.

(1) Open Start.

(2) Click on System and Security.

(3) Click the Change User Account Control settings option.

(4) Adjust the slider to the fourth position: Never notify (**It is not recommended for security reason**).

(5) Click on OK button.

References:

(1) [Disable ‘Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?’ dialog box](https://windowsreport.com/do-you-want-to-allow-this-app-to-make-changes-to-your-device/)

(2) [Turn off annoying User Account Control pop-ups, but be careful](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-run-everything-in-administrator-mode-and-why-you-shouldnt-do-it/)

Comment: Unfortunately I already have this done and am still getting the popup?

Comment: Can you please inform us on which level you had set the UAC setting?

Comment: I have it set to the fourth level like you have outlined. I think I may need to change settings in the regedit settings? But unsure of what to change.

Comment: Try to restart the machine and again try to run your code to check whether changes in the UAC are properly applied or not.

Comment: I have had this setting on the machine for the past number of months

Comment: Possible that some settings got corrupted or controlled by your organization. you can ask your administrator about it.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no one here today. I don;t think it's something like that though as I have three machines were this doesn't happen

Comment: Can you confirm with your IT guys during these working days? Than after if possible than you can try to update your machine with latest updates and again try to apply above settings. Let us know about your testing results.